# Passing function to child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, onclick

I'd like to pass functions to the child using props, and create several components that can be clicked on

**parent class:**

```
handleClick(i){
    alert(i);
}

render(){
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      items.push(
        <Item onClick={()=>this.handleClick(i)} />
      );
    }
    return <ul>{items}</ul>;
}
```

**child class:**

```
render() {
    return (
      <li onClick={this.props.onClick}> some names </li>
    );
}
```

But the result is different from what I expected.

I wanted the first element to `alert(0)`, the second element to`alert(1)`, and so on.

But instead, all elements shows `7` when I click on them. I guess that's because I'm always using the `i` after for-loop has finished.

I guess this is a problem about basic concepts of scopes or using closure or something, rather than a React problem. But still I can't find a right way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because of closure, since your are using `var` keyword for forLoop iterator, its scope will be the render function and the value passed to `handleClick` will always be the updated value of iterator. Use `let` keyword to solve closure issue

```
render(){
    var items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {  // let keyword for iterator
      items.push(
        <Item onClick={()=>this.handleClick(i)} />
      );
    }
    return <ul>{items}</ul>;
}
```

Even with var, you can solve the closure issue using anonymous function

```
render(){
    var items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      (function(index){
          items.push(
              <Item onClick={()=>this.handleClick(i)} />
          );
      }.bind(this))(i)
    }
    return <ul>{items}</ul>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! But what if I want to keep the `var` and add new local scope for each child? Is it possible?

Comment: I get the idea, but this actually doesn't work because the context of `this` is wrong.

Comment: @squiiiid, right, you use the context by .binding it